# difficulties in python and django integration

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\lanje\PycharmProjects\newenv\DjongoProject\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 113, in load_backend
    return import_module("%s.base" % backend_name)
  File "C:\python310\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 992, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 992, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 992, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1004, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mypackage'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\lanje\PycharmProjects\newenv\connectivitty\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\lanje\PycharmProjects\newenv\connectivitty\manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\lanje\PycharmProjects\newenv\DjongoProject\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 446, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\lanje\PycharmProjects\newenv\DjongoProject\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 420, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Users\lanje\PycharmProjects\newenv\DjongoProject\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\lanje\PycharmProjects\newenv\DjongoProject\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 116, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "C:\Users\lanje\PycharmProjects\newenv\DjongoProject\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 304, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "C:\python310\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
    conn = self.create_connection(alias)
  File "C:\Users\lanje\PycharmProjects\newenv\DjongoProject\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 208, in create_connection
    backend = load_backend(db["ENGINE"])
  File "C:\Users\lanje\PycharmProjects\newenv\DjongoProject\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 126, in load_backend
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: 'mypackage.backends.djongo' isn't an available database backend or couldn't be imported. Check the above exception. To use one of the built-in backends, use 'django.db.backends.XXX', where XXX is one of:
    'mysql', 'oracle', 'postgresql', 'sqlite3'
(DjongoProject) PS C:\Users\lanje\PycharmProjects\newenv\connectivitty>
```

'this is error from integration with dajngo and mongodb(djongo);
I want to use MongoDB as database backend for my Django project. Although there are many discussions on the net, I'm having troubles to integrate them well.'

Comment: go through [this](https://www.mongodb.com/compatibility/mongodb-and-django) well documented will help you.

Comment: i tried this but not works properly only pymongo and mongoengine connected with django but djongo are not connected throw same error.